# hibernate class not found

Tags: java, hibernate, noclassdeffounderror, cglib

I am new to hibernate and I'm trying to create a sample hibernate search project...
when I try to run the project  I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sf/cglib/proxy/CallbackFilter
    at org.hibernate.bytecode.cglib.BytecodeProviderImpl.getProxyFactoryFactory(BytecodeProviderImpl.java:33)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.buildProxyFactoryInternal(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:182)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.buildProxyFactory(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:160)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.<init>(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.<init>(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityEntityModeToTuplizerMapping.<init>(EntityEntityModeToTuplizerMapping.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.<init>(EntityMetamodel.java:269)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.<init>(AbstractEntityPersister.java:425)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.<init>(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.persister.PersisterFactory.createClassPersister(PersisterFactory.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:226)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1291)
    at de.laliluna.search.SessionFactoryUtil.<clinit>(SessionFactoryUtil.java:13)
    at de.laliluna.search.SearchTest.createSomeArticles(SearchTest.java:59)
    at de.laliluna.search.SearchTest.main(SearchTest.java:18)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.cglib.proxy.CallbackFilter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

I googled it and answers were to include asm and cglib libraries. I did so but still I get the same exception. what should I do?
I'm using eclipse for running project.

Comment: Seems you have a classpath problem. You are running from command-line or from IDE ?

Comment: Problem solved guys... I had use cglib-nodep-2.2.jar instead of cglib.jar in my libraries. thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've use `cglib-nodep-2.2.jar` instead of `cglib.jar` in your libraries.